# Laravel: 404 Not Found or 403 Forbidden

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, centos

I tried for the first time the Laravel Framework on my VPS.
In a folder where I have a other project folder (without any access problem) I create a project with "laravel new Test"

I changed the permission on "storage" and "bootstrap/cache".

Now I go to the page and...

- "/Test/" => returns 403 Forbid
- "/Test/index.php" => returns 404 Not Found

The mod_rewrite is enabled.
I set "AllowOverdrive All" to the main folder.

the .htaccess in the Test/public is the default one and i tried to change it to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Restart httpd. restart all the vps... nothing changed...

What I miss?

Comment: Is `Test/public` your documentRoot? What do you get if you navigate to `/Test/public/index.php`?

Comment: Yes! adding public I got the page!
How I can set the documentRoot to public?
So I can use "Site.it/Test/" without the "public"?

Comment: Depends on your server config, are you using apache? Search for apache set documentRoot + your OS (like ubuntu or centOS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default documentRoot for access the content is in the folder /public
So you can access with www.example.com/public/

You should change the default root for example.com to the public folder.